# How to trigger subscription_charged_successfully on sandbox?

Tags: braintree

I've created a listener to this webhook and I want to test it. I know there is a mock object with dummy data but since this is an important part of my application I want to test it with "real" data.

Is there any way to trigger this webhook on an existing subscription? Maybe manually charge an existing subscription so this webhook can be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted customer support on this issue and there is no way to trigger the webhook on an existing subscription.

At the time of creation, if the plan/subscription is set to charge immediately the webhook will be called. One other way is to set a 1 day trial period and the webhook will be called the next day.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this for a new subscription, this webhook will fire right when the subscription is started, so long as the first bill date is set to immediately.

As far as a subscription that is already active, you can simply [update the subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/) to include either a higher price, or a plan that has a price higher than the original subscription price.  Once this update is sent, the **subscription_charged_successfully** webhook will fire to your endpoint.

Comment: If you change the subscription price the new price will only take effect on the next billing cycle. The webhook is not called in this situation.

Comment: Ah, I had "Enable proration on upgrades" checked in my Processing --> Settings --> Recurring Billing options.  If you enable that, and change the price, it'll immediately charge that token.

Comment: The "enable proration on upgrades" settings on the recurring billing options does indeed trigger a subscription_charged_successfully event, which my endpoint receives. Good for testing.